# Как нарисовать векторное изображение canvas

Tags: java, android

Как используя `canvas` нарисовать `VectorDrawable`. Обычный `Drawable` у меня получается нарисовать конвертацией в `Bitmap`, но как нарисовать `VectorDrawable`, возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте этот вариант:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(Context context, int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        drawable = (DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)).mutate();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696488/getting-bitmap-from-vector-drawable